# Drupal 7, language changes back to EN after clicking on any link

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have 8 languages on my website. When I visit the website with different language prefix such as mysite.com/da and scroll down to click on any link. The language prefix changes to EN in URL. For example mysite.com/en/about

Can anyone please help me on it?

Thanks
Saeed Afzal

Answer (score 1):

in configuration, admin/config/regional/language/configure, modify language detection, the order there determinies wich language to use, it depends on how your languages are set, try moving on first place what you think how is confugured your site, set defalut value last. here are my settings on one site, your may be different.
[image]

Comment: I have the same set of configuration but could not find it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

**I found solution of this problem:**

Although I already have the same set of necessary configurations for multilingual modules. But actually, I was using "**base_path()**" in template files to create paths. So when the user changes the languages and scrolls down to the website to click any link. The language prefix was changing back to EN automatically.

**Here is solution I implemented:**

I simply created my own method in "template.php" file which returns the current language prefix such as "en, da or fr" etc.

```
function <your_theme_name>_get_lang_prefix(){
  global $language;
  $prefix =  $language->prefix . '/';
  return $prefix;
}
```

Finally, I modified the path in template **from**

```
<?php echo base_path(); ?>
```

**to**

```
<?php echo base_path() . <your_theme_name>_get_lang_prefix(); ?>
```

Now I can browse the website in all language prefix with content translation and etc.

Seem working perfectly.